# Random Dice Generator

Tags: java, random, compare

A run is a sequence of adjacent repeated values . Write a program that generates a sequence of random die tosses and that prints the die values, marking only the longest run. The program should take as input the total number of die tosses (ex 10), then print:

1 6 6 3 (2 2 2 2 2) 5 2

Im quite confused on how to compare each number in order to get the correct output. Maybe using an array to store the values. Any answers or input will be of help thank you!

```
 import java.util.Random;
 import java.util.Scanner;

 public class Dice 
 {
Random generator = new Random();
Scanner keyboard = new Scanner(System.in);

public void DiceCount()
{
int count;
int sides = 6;
int number;
System.out.println("How many die? ");
count = keyboard.nextInt();
for(int i=0; i < count; i++)
{
    number =  generator.nextInt(sides);
    System.out.print(number);
}

}
```

}

Comment: Try using a `List` (perhaps an `ArrayList`).

Comment: 1. Yes you may use an array, 2. Learn to use loop, so that you can iterate through the array to do your work. 3. Learn to proper indent your code.  4. `How may die?` it sounds so cruel to me

Comment: Make an array with length count and store the numbers in there. Keep track of 4 variables: the length of the longest repeating sequence, the length of the current sequence, the index at which the longest repeating sequence starts, and the starting index of the current repeating sequence.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
import java.util.Random;
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Dice {
    Random generator = new Random();
    Scanner keyboard = new Scanner(System.in);

    public void DiceCount() {
        int sides = 6;
        System.out.println("How many die? ");
        int count = keyboard.nextInt();
        int[] array = new int[count];
        int longestLength = 1, currentLength = 1, longestLengthIndex = 0, currentLengthIndex = 1;
        int currentNum = -1;
        for (int i = 0; i < count; i++) {
            array[i] = generator.nextInt(sides);
            System.out.print(array[i] + " ");
            if (currentNum == array[i]) {
                currentLength++;
                if (currentLength > longestLength) {
                    longestLengthIndex = currentLengthIndex;
                    longestLength = currentLength;
                }
            } else {
                currentLength = 1;
                currentLengthIndex = i;
            }
            currentNum = array[i];
        }
        System.out.println();
        for (int i = 0; i < count; i++)
            System.out.print((i == longestLengthIndex ? "(" : "") + array[i] + (i == (longestLengthIndex + longestLength - 1) ? ") " : " "));
    }
}
```

Note: this will only take the first longest range. So if you have 1123335666 it will do 112(333)5666.
If you need 112(333)5(666) or 1123335(666) then I leave that to you. It's very trivial.

Answer (score 2):

First, replace `int number;` with `int[] numbers = new int[count];`. Next, replace `number = ...` with `numbers[i] = ...`.

This will give you an array of random numbers (don't print them yet!). As you generate your numbers, note how many equal numbers you get in a row (add a special counter for that). Also add variable that stores the length of the longest run so far. Every time you get a number that's equal to the prior number, increment the counter; otherwise, compare the counter to the max, change the max if necessary, and set the counter to `1`. When you update the max, mark the position where the run starts (you can tell from the current position and the length of the run).

Now it's time to detect the longest run: go through the `numbers` array, and put an opening parenthesis where the run starts. Put a closing parenthesis when you reach the end of the run, and finish the printing to complete the output for the assignment.

Answer (score 0):

````java
import java.util.Random;

public class Dice {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        //make rolls
        Random rand = new Random();
        int[] array = new int[20];
        int longestRun = 1;
        int currentRun = 1;
        int longestRunStart = 0;
        int currentRunStart = 1;

        System.out.print("Generated array: \n");
        for (int i = 0; i < array.length; i++) {
            array[i] = rand.nextInt(6); //add random number
            System.out.print(array[i] + " "); //print array
            if (i != 0 && array[i - 1] == array[i]) {
                //if new number equals last number...
                currentRun++; //record current run
                if (currentRun > longestRun) {
                    longestRunStart = currentRunStart; //set index to newest run
                    longestRun = currentRun; //set above record to current run
                }
            } else {
                //if new number is different from the last number...
                currentRun = 1; //reset the current run length
                currentRunStart = i; //reset the current run start index
            }
        }

        //record results
        System.out.print("\nIdentifying longest run: \n");
        for (int i = 0; i < longestRunStart; i++) { System.out.print(array[i] + " "); } //prints all numbers leading up to the run
        System.out.print("( "); //start parentheses
        for (int i = longestRunStart; i < (longestRunStart + longestRun); i++) { System.out.print(array[i] + " "); } //prints the run itself
        System.out.print(") "); //end parentheses
        for (int i = (longestRunStart + longestRun); i < 20; i++) { System.out.print(array[i] + " "); } //all remaining numbers
    }
}```
````